# Is there a chrome extension that can search for multiple key words at a time

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-chrome-extensions

The default search <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> could only search for one word at a moment, and only highlight the current key word.

But I want to search multiple word at one moment and highlight them all,

Is there a chrome extension for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be. Never tried it myself, though. [efTwo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eftwo-f2-advanced-find-on/ccaikggmppdolhcehimngikgiafmdcep?hl=en#search/eftwo?hl=en).

Additional info on the extension: [efTwo Supercharges Chrome's Find on Page..](http://lifehacker.com/5831195/eftwo-supercharges-chromes-find-on-page-by-finding-multiple-words-at-once-word-variations)

Answer (score 0):

Multi-highlight is the best for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multi-highlight/pfgfgjlejbbpfmcfjhdmikihihddeeji